# Filtering and pagination in Django 2x

Tags: django, pagination, filtering

It looks like the django-filter-mixin still has issues with Django 2x. So I'm trying to do it the 'old fashioned way'. The following starts with the filter criteria which works without fault, The pagination code is included but it is not working, I can't figure out if it's an issue with the view or the template (both included)

views.py

```
def allcontainer(request):
    allcontainer = Container.objects.all()
    container_list = Container.objects.all()
    user_list = User.objects.all()

    type = request.GET.get('type')
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    rack = request.GET.get('rack')
    shelf = request.GET.get('shelf')

    if (
    type =='' or type is None and
    name =='' or name is None and
    rack =='' or rack is None and
    shelf =='' or shelf is None
    ):
        allcontainer = allcontainer

    if type !='' and type is not None:
        allcontainer = allcontainer.filter(container_type__iexact=type)
    if name !='' and name is not None:
        allcontainer = allcontainer.filter(container_name__iexact=name)
    if rack !='' and rack is not None:
        allcontainer = allcontainer.filter(location_id__location_name__iexact=rack)
    if shelf !='' and shelf is not None:
        allcontainer = allcontainer.filter(location_id__location_sub_name__iexact=shelf)

    qs = allcontainer
    paginator = Paginator(qs, 25)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        pub = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        pub = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
       pub = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    # url_filter = PublicationFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)

    context = {
    'container':allcontainer,
    'type': type,
    'pub':pub,
    # 'url_filter':url_filter
    # name
    # rack
    # shelf
    }

    return render(request, 'container/allcontainer.html', context)
```

template

...

```
  {% if pub.has_other_pages %}
  <p>a</p>
  {% if pub.has_previous %}
  <p>b</p>
  <a href="?page={{ pub.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
  <!-- </li> -->
  {% else %}
  <li class="disabled"><span>???</span></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% for i in pub.paginator.page_range %}
  {% if pub.number == i %}
  <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
  {% else %}
  <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if pub.has_next %}
  <li><a href="?page={{ pub.next_page_number }}">next</a></li>
  {% else %}
  <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
  {% endif %}

  {% endif %}
</section>
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code replace

`pub = paginator.page(page)`

with

`pub = paginator.get_page(page)`